# how to get entry's value from tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some code to get square root, so i'm input my value
this value is `x1`
i can print this in `getSquareRoot ():`

but how i can get this value to next operations?

for example, then i need to make sum this `x1` with `a=1`

this should be `25 + 1`

but idk how to get this `25` from my input form, can only print this

```
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

def getSquareRoot ():  
    x1 = entry1.get() # i need this value
    
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text= float(x1)**0.5)
    canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label1)
    
    print(x1) # i can print this

    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Get the Square Root', command=getSquareRoot)
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: just add `return x1` at end of your `getSquareRoot()` function, not quite sure what you're trying to do?

Comment: Script work, also print, but button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Get the Square Root', command=getSquareRoot), if nothing special, you can set global x1 in getSquareRoot(), then you can use it anywhere.

Comment: @JasonYang my button should use `getSqureRoot()`, so that's way i'm need this `x1` inside